# Embedding into dual space

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $X$ be a Banach space and $X^*$ its dual

Does anyone have an example where $X$ does not embed isomorphically/isometrically into $X^*$.

Does $C([0,1])$ embed isomorphically/isometrically into its dual?

Comment: You forgot to mention that $X$ is infinite dimensional.

Comment: Yes, $X$ is infinite dimensional

Comment: Isn't $L^p$ a counterexample for suitable $p$?

Comment: I think you have to make clear what you mean by "embed isomorphically". To me, an isomorphism is bounded, injective **and surjective**. Is this what you mean? Why do you use "embed" then?

Answer (score 3):

If $X=l^{p}$ with $1<p<\infty $ then $X^{*}$ does not contain an isomorphic copy of $C[0,1]$. To prove this we need two well known theorems from FA:

Theorem 1

(Pitt) and bounded linear map from $l^{r}$ to $l^{s}$ is compact if $1<s<r<\infty$.

Theorem 2

$C[0,1]$ is universal for separable Banach spaces (in the sense any separable Banach space can be embedded isometrically in  $C[0,1]$). Ref.: Geometric FA by Holmes.

Now let $q>p^{*}$ where $p^{*}$ is the conjugate of $p$.  Suppose there is an isomorphism $T: C[0,1] \to X^{*}=l^{p^{*}}$. Let $S:l^{q} \to C[0,1]$ be an isometric isomorphism (into). Then $T\circ S$ is compact by Pitt's Theorem. But this map is also an isomorphism. It is easy to see that there cannot be an isomorphism on an infinite dimensional space which is compact.

Comment: For the last part note that $\|T(S(x))\| \geq C \|x\|$ for some $c$. If $\{x_n\}$ is any sequence in the unit ball of $l^{q}$ then $T(S(x_n))$ has a convergent subsequence and the inequality implies that the corresponding subsequence of $\{x_n\}$ is Cauchy. This makes the unit ball of $l^{q}$ compact, a contradictioin.

Comment: Hi Kavi. Thanks for your answer. I think my question was a little ambiguous, or I may not have understood your answer. It seems you showed there is a dual that does not contain an isomorphic copy of $C([0,1])$. I'm wondering if $C([0,1])$ embeds into its dual $C([0,1])^*$

Comment: $X$ does not embed isomorphically in $X^{*}$ if $X=l^{p}$ with $p>2$ (by the Pitt's Theorem argument). I do not know if $C[0,1]$ embeds in its dual.